# Methods for fast developing GWT-EJB based applications

Tags: java, gwt, ejb

I'm searching fast method for developing GWT-EJB applications.

Some requirements:

1. I want to use gwt dev-mode during development.
2. My gwt-servlet must call EJB's methods (problem here is that GWT's default servlet-container is Jetty  - isn't Java EE compatible).
3. Fast developing of EJBs.

Only way is to configure Glassfish (any app-server) as GWT dev-mode app-server?

P.S. I have multi-module maven project.

Comment: Please mention what you have tried and also any blocking items you encountered. Note : You can always use tomcat or glassfish with GWT even in dev mode by setting up external deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Develop/build/assemble your GWT app as a WAR, package into an EAR with the relevant EJBs and lookup/call these via JNDI.

Cheers,

Comment: As I understand you suggest me to separate my projects into two modules - gwt-module and ejb-module?

Comment: Yes, something like that; specifically keep the EJBs separate from the GWT client+server code.